# Unable to find elements by tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio

Hi I'm fairly new to web automation and I'm testing new things out.
I'm having trouble getting the list of elements as shown in the picture. i have selected the Xpath of the highlighted code but still no success.

```
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement LauncheddAppTest = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpath))

    List<WebElement> DLauncheddAppTest = LauncheddAppTest.findElements(By.tagName('li'))

    println("\n\nIm inside search and click")
    println("\n\n Size is: "+DLauncheddAppTest.size())
```

the size returned is 0 so the tag "li" was not found.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK0yO.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZU17.png)
[Code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLa8M.png)

Any. poiters would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please add the code from the code block image as text to facilitate debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below xpath :

```
//div[@class='DivFiles']/li
```

and Use it like below :

```
List<WebElement> DLauncheddAppTest = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='DivFiles']/li"))
```

and print the size like this :

```
println("\n\n Size is: "+DLauncheddAppTest.size())
```

This answer assumes that A `div` has unique class `DivFiles`

Comment: Hi thank you for your time :). i tried what u suggested and it throwed a "text not parsed"  on the console.  it happened right after the "List<WebElement> DLauncheddAppTest = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='DivFiles']/li"))" was executed

Comment: Can you share entireStacktrace ? In my answer it should only print size of the list.

Comment: Size did not get printed ?

Comment: yes it did not. It showed only text not parsed

Comment: that may be cause `"//div[@class='DivFiles']/li"`, I am not into Katalon.. How did you parse your `Xpath` in the question ?

Comment: called the function using "i attached new images for u to see" Searchlistandclick.selectValueFromUnorderedList("//div[@class='DivFiles']/li",items[0]).

Comment: You are not using the code that I have given you